# Play Framework with JPA packages not found

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am trying to create an application using Playframework 2.1.1 and JPA/Hibernate 4.2.1.
I followed [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaJPA) documentation, added these dependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.1.Final",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
    jdbc,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaJpa
)
```

as well as the persistence.xml

My Problem is that Eclipse(Juno) still cannot resolve the import play.db.jpa.*

Has anyone had a similar problem or any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you mean "play.db.jpa" ?

Comment: rerun the `eclipse` command in the Play console, and then refresh the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: still no success, I guess it's not an eclipse-problem.

Comment: I found the libraries I needed in my play-folder and added them manually to the build-path. Though I don't know why they diappeared, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the libraries in the play-folder and **manually** added them to the `build path`. Though I don't know why they disappeared, it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You try to do this way:

```
play clean-all
```

in play command:

```
run eclipse
```

or
in terminal:

```
play eclipsify
```

then **re-import** project

It's worked for me. Hope it useful for you.